# TV show where groups of three heroes and villains battle using cards that gave them abilities and creature transformations

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animation

I've recently gone on a binge of shows I've watched as a child and one show recently came to mind

In this show there are three protagonists. Two males and one female. The female being related to the villain one way or another.

The crew battle against bad guys in groups of threes. The battle in this show involve these cards that grant the characters the abilities of the creature and the ability to turn into it.

The format for episodes where pretty similar.

The crew would battle with the enemies for that episode and battle them two times.

The first battle had them only using the abilities of the cards and losing to the enemies.

The second battle is when they transformed into whatever was on their cards and winning.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when would you have watched this?

Comment: Can you describe what any of the characters looked like? Hair colour, physical build, clothing, etc.

Comment: Also, if you can specify any shows with a similar premise that aren't the one you're for, that'd be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of ***[RedaKai](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2021833/)*** (2011-2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu):

> *Redakai: Conquer the Kairu*, also known simply as *Redakai*, is an animated series that premiered on YTV and later Teletoon in Canada on July 9, 2011, on Cartoon Network in the United States on July 16, 2011 and on Canal J and Gulli in France on October 22, 2011. The series was created by Vincent Chalvon Demersay and David Michel and was co-produced by Canada's Spin Master Entertainment and France's Marathon Media in association with Canal J and Gulli. Like *Totally Spies!* and *Martin Mystery*, which were also produced by Marathon, the show's animation style has been compared to that of anime.

> The series revolves around Ky, a 15-year-old student of ancient martial arts, who embarks on an epic quest to find the Kairu, a primordial alien energy source. Aided by his friends Maya and Boomer, Ky travels the world searching for the Kairu while attempting to make sure that his extraterrestrial teenage alien adversaries don’t find it first.

The show does involves trios of kids fighting card battles and turning into monsters, with the protagonists being two boys and a girl.